# Posting a textarea with html content fails `No data received`

Tags: post, iis-7.5

ok guys,
so here's another weird one:

i have the following form:

```
<form method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Edit article</legend>

        <label>Description<textarea name="txtDescription"><%=article.Description %></textarea></label>
        <label>Content<textarea name="txtContent"><%=article.Content %></textarea></label>

    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" class="fr" value="save changes" />
</form>
```

there is nothing on the code behind page beside getting the article.
the page loads very fast, under 1 second, with that data in the textarea's.

when i try to submit this form, the page takes forever to load (actualy, it does not load at all, but fails after a few minuets with `No data received`.
the textarea content is just some html, not large (about 2-4kb each text area)

i have tried adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, with no success, the same thing happens.
i have managed to narrow it down to the `txtContent` textarea, (i removed the `description` textarea)
and the page fails.

what makes this even worse is that if i open the page in the browser on my server,
it works with no problem, i can post, and it is all working as it should.
if i try to access the page from a remote machine, the post fails.

Anyone has any idea as to what happens here?

EDIT: just to make sure, i have created a simple HTML document with the following in it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/admin/">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="/admin/articles/">Articles</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    <form method="post" action="test.html">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Edit article</legend>

            <label>Content<textarea name="txtcontent"></textarea></label>

        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" class="fr" value="save changes" />
    </form>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

this still fails.

EDIT: the test code shown here is the minimal code that is not working.
the actual form is larger, and if i remove the `txtcontent` textarea from the form,
the form submits with no problem, including the `description` textarea.

EDIT: Content-Length: 1555 / Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

EDIT: i have uninstalled and reinstalled iis, and re-registered .NET
the problem is still there.

Comment: what language and version is this? And does it work if you post normal text content (i.e. no html tags)?

Comment: C#, posting the same content without html tags (which are mostly `<p>` and `<br />` still fails. again, for this textarea only. also, remove the C# part, and putting the content directly in the textarea, still fails.

Comment: Did you find this solution?? as i m also facing this issue??

Comment: yes, it had something to do with `get` and `post` not registered on iis for some reason, had to add it to the web.config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final note:
i have uninstalled IIS, Re-Installed IIS, Re-Registered .net framework,
and it seems to work fine now.
the reason for the original problem, unknown

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check....

What language are you using, e.g. ASP.NET WebForms, ASP.NET MVC and version?

I can see you are using

```
<form method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

In ASP.NET web forms, you would normally declare the form tag as

```
<form runat="server">
```

In ASP.NET MVC it would be similar to

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(......))
{
}
```

The other issue is you are posting HTML tags, by default ASP.NET will not allow this due to security reasons. Lookup XSS and be sure to understand the risks before disabling this feature.

Comment: as detailed above, even a basic HTML form with no server side language fails with this specific textarea.